# I am trying to make the text in a button change color when I hover over in with the mouse using CSS

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a wordpress website and I have a button in the header menu which is called 'Join as a tradesperson'.

http://prntscr.com/px7mdt

It has a green border and white background and the text is black.

I wanted the background of the button to change to green (color: #25ad00) and the text to change to white (color: #fff) when I hover over it.

I have added the following code to custom css is the dashboard:

```
body #menu-item-1847 a{
    color:#000;
}
#menu-item-1847 a{
    font-weight: 700;
    border: 2px solid #25ad00;
        border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 2px 20px
    }
#menu-item-1847 a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #25ad00;
}
```

...but now when I hover over the button the background turns green but the text remains black:

http://prntscr.com/px7o9u

I was jut wandering what is wrong with the code as I thought the

```
#menu-item-1847 a:hover {
    color: #fff;
```

...would change the color of the text to white when I hover over it?

Thank you

Comment: Hi Jas, just so you know, using !important is not good practice. It means that you are not scoping your styles correctly. !important will override everything (bar inline css containing !important). Look to scope your css better before turning to !important.

Comment: @Spangle Hi Spangle, thanks for this. I see. I think the code above was conflicting with CSS I added before for another button, also in the menu bar, which had the opposite color scheme: 
```#menu-item-1272 a:hover {
 color: #000;
 background-color: #fff;```
Is there any way this could have been avoided, just for the benefit of others also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about your DOM's CSS specificity you can make your code working without adding !important.

Just increase the CSS specificity. (share your HTML I will explain you this with CSS specificity)

Please read about CSS specificity. Using !important is not good practice. It is not clean code. Go through these articles.

[Don't use !important instead increase CSS specificity](https://j11y.io/css/dont-use-important/)
[Is Using !important is a right choice?](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)

Comment: Hi @sabitha kuppusamy , sorry I just got this. Thank you very much. I read the articles u sent but I don't think my knowledge is good enough to solve this issue without it.
The button I am trying to edit is on my menu bar, I wanted the button to turn green and the the text white upon hovering over it. There is another button on the same menu which does the opposite here: http://prntscr.com/pxpgue, "post a job" and "join as a tradesperson". This is the CSS I used for them:  http://prntscr.com/pxpial
http://prntscr.com/pxpix6
Do you think it is posssible to do the same without the !important?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Can you please share your HTML as well? I'll help you.

Comment: Hey thanks. I'm not sure which file that's in, is that in the functions.php?

Comment: Yes, please share it! I want the DOM element in which you have added the ID. Are you adding '#menu-item-1847' dynamically?

Comment: I'm really sorry about this but I am a complete newbie you see and I don't fully understand the terminology. Regarding the '#menu-item-1847' I just found it using inspect element from here: https://prnt.sc/pxrr7z
And then typed in the CSS code manually in the custom CSS section of my wordpress dashboard.
Here is a screenshot of my complete functions.php
https://prnt.sc/pxsmhv
http://prntscr.com/pxsmrm
http://prntscr.com/pxsn23
Again I apologise if this is not the right file.

Comment: @Jas  DOM element is the Document Object Model. Eg, div, p, li, etc are all DOM elements. So with the help of your chrome developer tool screenshot. I'm able to give you a solution. instead of this, #menu-item-1847 a:hover try this #menu-logged_out > #menu-item-1847 a:hover and remove the !important, Let me know if it is working.

Comment: Hey @sabitha kuppusamy, thanks a lot!! you are a genius! https://prnt.sc/pxunfd and this is when I hover over it now http://prntscr.com/pxuqhv. I am still learning but I will definitely be looking more into this rule and the info you sent. Thanks again!!

Comment: @Jas That's great to hear! Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

To overwrite existing CSS, add `!important` like this:

```
#menu-item-1847 a:hover {
color: #fff!important;
background-color: #25ad00!important;
}
```

Comment: Hey thank you. That solved it! Yes,there was existing CSS code for another button which had the opposite color scheme when hovering over it. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can using `!important` statement like this.
(If you specified the selector correctly, if not, double check the selector #menu-item-1847)

```
#menu-item-1847 a:hover {
    color: #fff!important;
}
```

It means, something like:

> Use me, if there is nothing important else around!

Comment: thank you for the explanation, It worked perfectly!!